# How to monitor outgoing messages for the IoTHub built-in event hub endpoint?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub, azure-monitoring

When using an Event Hub I can monitor number of outgoing messages (namespace: microsoft.eventhub/namespaces, metricID: OutgoingMessages).

Is it possible to monitor the number of outgoing messages for the IoTHub build-in Event Hub as well?

There is Routing: messages delivered to messages/events (namespace: microsoft.devices/iothubs, metricID: d2c.endpoints.egress.builtIn.events) but this only shows number of messages send to Event Hub and not how many messages were consumed from the built-in Event Hub.

Comment: I believe the answer provided by Matthijs van der Veer on similar thread also applies to your case. You can use Service Bus Explorer for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71066825/how-to-get-older-data-uploaded-by-devices-to-azure-iot-hub

Comment: I think I can consume and inspect the messages on the IoTHub with it but I cannot observe number of outgoing messages on the Event Hub over all consumer groups. Thanks for the pointer though @asergaz

Comment: I don't think such a metric exists for the built-in event hub. It would make for a good feature request. A workaround would be to use your own event hub as an endpoint instead.

Comment: This question relates with: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/747648/index.html

Comment: @MatthijsvanderVeer: Do you know what would be a good method for submitting a feature request to the relevant team? 

Comment: I think [this](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/fcb810f7-f824-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034) is the right channel.  The link posted by @asergaz might also help, the people there can get in touch with the teams.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @MatthijsvanderVeer. The question linked by asergaz is a cross-post from me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Matthijs van der Veer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8800237/matthijs-van-der-veer) and [jayeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409068/jayeff). Posting your discussions as answer to help other community members.

> **"Number of outgoing messages on the Event Hub over all consumer
> groups"** feature doesn't exists in the built-in event hub. As an
> workaround, you can use the own event hub as an endpoint.