# How to get older data uploaded by devices to Azure IoT hub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I have a few Raspberry Pi devices uploading data to Azure IoT Hub. I can see all the data on Device Explorer. But is there any way I can see the data of specific time frame? Let's say complete data of last 1 hour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with [Service Bus Explorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer). The name might suggest it's only for Service Bus, but it has Event Hub and IoT Hub support as well. To see the data for the last hour, do the following:

Copy the Event Hub compatible endpoint from the Azure Portal and strip off the EntityPath. Example:
`Endpoint=sb://REDACTED.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey=REDACTED=;EntityPath=hub-name`

becomes:
`Endpoint=sb://REDACTED.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey=REDACTED=`

Open Service Bus Explorer and create a new IoT  Hub Listener.

[image: Service Bus Explorer]

Add the connection string without the entity path and add the entity path as the Endpoint.

[image: Enter Credentials]

This will open a new listener window. In the window, you can select a start time. Select a time one hour back. The minimum retention period is a day, but if you decide to choose a time further in the past, that time should be within the retention period of the endpoint. If you select a time before the retention period, you will see events from the beginning of the retention period.

[image: Set Start Time]

If you want to inspect the events, you can go to the Events tab and have a look at the data.